# TdsParserStateObject - disposing ? Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using EF and have problem with `TdsParserStateObject`.

I'm calling this method many times :

```
 public void SaveDataFromERP(string synchronizationType, string xml,int errorsHandlingPercentagePartition)
    {
        var param1 = new SqlParameter("XML", SqlDbType.Xml);
        param1.Value = xml;
        var param2 = new SqlParameter("PartitionedPackagePercentage", SqlDbType.Int);
        param2.Value = errorsHandlingPercentagePartition;
        ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<dynamic>(
            $"exec [Synchronization].[Import{synchronizationType}] @XML,  @PartitionedPackagePercentage", param1 , param2 );
}
```

My repository consists of

```
SynchronizationRepository : ISynchronizationRepository
{
  private readonly POSDBContext _context = new POSDBContext();
  public void SaveData(string typeName, string xmlFile, int errorsHandlingPartitionPercentage)
    {
        _context.SaveData(typeName, xmlFile,errorsHandlingPartitionPercentage);
    }
 }
```

When I call `ExecuteStoreQuery` I can see new object in memory `TdsParserStateObject`.

Unfortunately I must call this method in sequence many times(a lot of data). The result is about 60 `TdsParserStateObject` and it take a lot of memory.

Moreover these objects do not disappear after some time.

Is it possible to dispose them ?

[image]

Comment: Any luck with this? We're having the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42761087/system-outofmemoryexception-during-nunit-tests-with-localdb

Comment: same here - no answers?

Comment: Having the same issue. The only answer didn't help much.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved my own issue to some degree by removing:

`"MultipleActiveResultSets=True"`

From my connection string. My connections were being made on background threads so this goes someway to explaining why I was seeing the increase:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/enabling-multiple-active-result-sets